# How do I separate @types into different cards using JSON-LD?

Tags: json, schema, json-ld, linked-data, structured-data

The Structured Data Testing Tool doesn't separate my @types into different sections, and places all of the @types into one main type: Product. How can i separate the types so that each are validated as their own container?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/69z3C.jpg (I want to go from the 1st picture to something similar to the 3rd picture, please excuse the errors/warnings)

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Product1",
  "image": "http://mycompany.com/logo.png",
  "color": "example",

  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "1",
    "ratingCount": "0",
    "worstRating": "1",
    "bestRating": "5"
  },
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Company1",
    "logo": "http://mycompany.com/logo.png"
  }
```

I have more markup than this, but I think this shows enough of what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this, but each is different because the **meaning** is different.

For example, if you are speaking the sentence "My Product has an AggregateRating of `<values>` and is branded by an Organization", you would state the above.

Alternatively, you could make several individual statements and link them together. For example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": {
        "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
        "id": "@id",
        "graph": "@graph",
        "type": "@type"
    },
    "graph": [
        {
            "type": "Organization",
            "id": "#001",
            "name": "Big-Daddy",
            "image": "http://bigdaddy.com/logo.png"
        },
        {
            "type": "Product",
            "id": "#002",
            "name": "Big-2",
            "image": "http://bigdaddy.com/big-2.png",
            "brand": {
                "type": "Organization",
                "id": "#001"
            },
            "aggregateRating": {
                "type": "AggregateRating",
                "ratingValue": "3",
                "ratingCount": "20",
                "worstRating": "3",
                "bestRating": "4"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Product",
            "id": "#003",
            "name": "Big-3",
            "image": "http://bigdaddy.com/big-3.png",
            "brand": {
                "type": "Organization",
                "id": "#001"
            },
            "aggregateRating": {
                "type": "AggregateRating",
                "ratingValue": "3",
                "ratingCount": "20",
                "worstRating": "2",
                "bestRating": "5"
            }
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

In speaking mode this says: "I have two products, each with AggregateRating of `<values>`, that are branded by Big-Daddy."

I can think of several other variations, but each would **mean** something different.

However, the Google SDTT acknowledges two Products in the above example.